# How to connect to a WebServer mode H2 database in console?

Tags: h2

On H2 documentation, it says [**only the web server supports browser connections**](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server). Does this mean we can only access the H2 Database by console in WebServer mode, not TcpServer? But when I do below test, the result is totally not as expected.

```
public class TestMem {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        conn.createStatement().execute("create table test(id int)");

        Server server = Server.createTcpServer().start();//1.TcpServer
//      Server server = Server.createWebServer().start();//2.WebServer

        System.out.println("Server started and connection is open.");
        System.out.println("URL: jdbc:h2:" + server.getURL() + "/mem:test");

        Thread.sleep(5*60*1000);

        System.out.println("Stopping server and closing the connection");
        server.stop();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

If I start a TcpServer, I can visit the DB by this url: *jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:test* in console.

```
//Use TcpServer
  Server server = Server.createTcpServer().start();
```

But when I start a WebServer, I tried to connect use *jdbc:h2:http ://localhost:8082/mem:test*, below exception will throw: **IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"; "http ://localhost:8082/mem:test.h2.db" [90031-172] 90031/90031 (Help).**

```
//Use WebServer
  Server server = Server.createWebServer().start();
```

Here are my questions

1. Can we access the WebServer mode h2 DataBase in console? How?
2. Did I misunderstand the H2 documentation about the **Using the Server** section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [H2 Console tool](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#tutorial_starting_h2_console) (created using `Server.createWebServer`) is a web server and a small web application that allows you to connect to a database (any JDBC database) using a web browser (such as Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, and so on).

The [H2 TCP Server](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server) (created using `Server.createTcpServer`) is a server for H2 JDBC clients. It is not a web server and not a web application. You can not connect to this server from a web browser.

If you start both the Console tool (web server) and the TCP server, then you can connect using a browser to the Console tool, which can then connect to a H2 database in server mode.

About database URLs: see the [documentation about database URLs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url).

Comment: Do you mean **Server.createWebServer** only create an web server, not a database server, and **Server.createTcpServer** will create a database server?

Comment: Probably not the original question, but I wonder if it would be possible to hotwire a JDBC client to connect to a database where you only have access through a H2 console?

Comment: @MichaelMunsey I don't understand, sorry. I think it's better if you start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Some additional comment on the answer of Thomas Mueller:

> "The H2 Console tool ... a small web application"

You can see it as a "small alternative" to database applications like DBeaver or Navicat.

In addition to that, if you start the H2 console from within the same JVM as your H2 database (which has for example been started with org.h2.Tools.RunScript.execute(...)), you will be able to use the "embedded mode" of the H2 Console tool to connect to your H2 database without using a H2 TCP server.

(Other database tools like DBeaver will not run in the same JVM. If you use the embedded H2 mode with DBeaver, you will be connected to an extra temporary database inside the JVM of DBeaver.)

**Example for embedded mode**

If you started a H2 database "test_database" on port 8085 from within the same JVM, with the option DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 and without also starting a TCP server ... start a web browser and enter following address to show the H2 Console tool web application:

```
http://localhost:8085
```

Use for example following settings to connect in embedded mode:

```
Setting Name: Generic H2 (Embedded)
Driver Class: org.h2.Driver
JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:mem:test_database;MODE=MySQL
UserName: {user, e.g. root}
Password: {password, e.g mypassword}
```

**Example for server mode**

If you started a TCP server you can connect to the H2 database in server mode. You can do this with

- the H2 Console tool (from within the same JVM or from within another JVM)
- any other suitable database tool (e.g DBeaver).

Start a web browser and enter for example following address to show the H2 Console tool web application:

```
http://localhost:8085
```

Use for example following settings to connect in server mode:

```
Setting Name: Generic H2 (Server)
Driver Class: org.h2.Driver
JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9095/mem:test_database;MODE=MySQL
UserName: {user, e.g. root}
Password: {password, e.g mypassword}
```

You can also use the url

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9095/mem:test_database;MODE=MySQL
```

to connect for example with DBeaver.

Comment: Thank you for a tantalising addendum.  I would like a _regular_ TCP server with multi-user access and I think it would be _nice to have_ web client (tool) to access to same server instance.   Re-reading your comment, is seems like you are telling _us_ this is possible.  How?  And related (I feel), what is the context for these _settings_ you have offered?  A `properties` file, command line, URL (JDBC connection), etc.?

Comment: Or in simple terms.  More or less, a multi-user SQLite like tool (_in Java_).  _Too much?_